# Where to find Flutter Engine source?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, text-rendering

I am developing an app that displays PDFs, found that Flutter paragraph layout method is so slow, I want to check native Android and iOS source of **layout** method, where can I find it?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paragraph/layout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many git repository for it. But you should choose most trusted link given below.

git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/flutter/engine